# TSQL Make All Words That Are Missing Vowels Upper Case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having a difficult time producing a script that makes all sub strings within a string upper case if they contain no vowels.

For example: 
'Hammer Products Llc' Should be: 'Hammer Product LLC'. 
Or:
'49 Ways Ltd' Should be: '49 Ways LTD'.

As a application developer I am still working on the concept of TSQL Set based processing and avoiding iterations whenever possible. So aside from the task of identifying those rows that have words within them that are missing vowels... for the life of me I can not think of a Set based way to identify and then further update those sub strings other than iterating through them.

So far I am working on the first part in trying to identify those rows that have sub strings that are missing vowels. My only thought is to take each string and Split() it with a customized function... then taking each of the split words and testing them to see if it is all consonants. Then if all consonants perform an update on that word.

My major concern is that this approach will be very heavy to process. This is a real brain twister and any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: TSQL does not support regex out of the box, which is really what you want to use here.

Comment: My previous employer's name was `XXX Pte Ltd`.  Notice carefully that there is a vowel is the abbreviation `Pte`.

Comment: Depending on the size of the text fields and number of records, you may want to consider a CLR function with proper REGEX syntax to accommodate speed and flexibility. As you guessed it, doing it in tsql (with parsing, cte, and somehow making into a convoluted set-based transformation) was about 100x slower for a similar issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can readily find which strings have a word with no vowels with something like:

```
where ' ' + lower(str) + ' ' not like '% %[aeiou]% %'
```

Do note that this doesn't take punctuation into account.  That gets a bit harder, because SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions.

Modifying a part of a string to be upper case is much, much harder.  Your idea of using `split()` is definitely one approach.  Another is to write a user-defined function.

My recommendation, though, is to do this work in another tool.  If you are learning SQL, try using it for tasks it is more suited for.

Comment: Thank you... So maybe you would recommend a CLR function? Or do you think this should be completely handled at the application level?

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs . . . You can write the function as a CRL or using T-SQL.  It would probably be a lot easier in an application language such as C#, java, or python.

Comment: Thank you... I didn't think it was possible to do this type of update as a set... but I wanted to get a second from a seasoned SQL developer.